# Installing openSUSE 12.1 on an Asus ZenBook UX32VD

Tags: networking, boot, system-installation, opensuse, bios

## The back story

My boss who hates the idea of Windows and virtualization brought me his fancy new ZenBook UX32VD wanting openSUSE 12.1 to be installed on it. So far I have hit issue after issue and can't seem to find a lot of information on the problems I have encountered, and I figured what better place to start collecting it than right here.

[Laptop Manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/UX32A/E7165_eManual_UX32A_UX32VD_Z104.pdf)

The first issue I ran into when installing 12.1 on a ZenBook is there is no disk drive. I solved this by making a bootable USB drive.

The second issue I ran into is that the installer doesn't seem support the USB 3.0 ports on the ZenBook. Fortunately USB 3.0 is backwards compatible, so I had to create another bootable USB on a 2.0 USB with openSUSE 12.1's installation data.

The third issue I hit is a black screen after the installer loads udev; screen just completely goes black and nothing comes back up. It looks like the drives are still busy and loading is going on in the background, but nothing happens. I think this is the Optimus technology making openSUSE choke, so I figured using VESA mode would take care of it. Nope! Instead for some reason using the installation parameter nomodeset in the openSUSE boot menu works which is strange because according to my understanding nomodeset is the same as selecting VESA. Maybe I'm wrong? but nomodeset works for installation.

The fourth issue I ran into is that there are no drivers to support the Intel wifi in the stock installation of 12.1. In addition to this issue; there are no ethernet ports. Instead Asus has included a USB to ethernet adapter and I can't find out the specs on it; perhaps it's not working because it USB 3.0 ethernet adapter? I can't find out and it's not working.

## The Question

After my install is completed and I reboot from the KDE desktop, it boots straight into the system BIOS! The drives are detected by the BIOS and listed in the SATA configuration, but there are no boot options and no options to set boot options. All I get is delete boot options.

> How can I get the newly-installed system to boot?

Comment: I stopped reading after the second issue that you managed to solve. This is not a blog. For the issues that you haven't solved, please open new questions: 1 issue per question. Thanks.

Comment: while this is my first post to this Unix and Linux section of the stack exchange I am not new to the stack. TO inform you the stack exchange is a collection of 83 Q & A sites that are all aimed towards developing solutions. This thread contains unresolved issues along with useful information that might assist others one day facing the same problems unified under one topic. Please refrain from posting comments unless they are helpful.

Comment: You are right, there is some useful information in the post. You could post the first two issues as questions and then answer your own question. But grouping all the questions in a single thread is not the SE way of doing things, this is not a mailing list. I mentions this for your benefit, because I happen to want you to get the answers that you need.

Comment: These issues are specific to the Asus Zenbook UX32VD Installation of openSUSE 12.1, and at this point your strategy is a matter of opinion. If you were really trying to help answers happen here you'd stop neging the thread. That way users that actually read from top to bottom might actually be able to provide some real assistance .

Comment: Even if you find @dotancohen's comment to be rude, he has a point.  I'm looking for a `tl;dr:` at the bottom of your post.  Just start with one question and make it clear and concise.  If people need more background, they'll ask for it.  Hopefully someone can help you troubleshoot then.  Hey I've been downvoted and heckled for crappy questions before, but c'est la vie.

Comment: There really isn't a lot of research or discussion happening in this field because this ultrabook is new and with new things I find that anything can be the problem and to expect just about anything to turn up as the solution. Maybe my means of delivery is causing this issue and perhaps using an external disc drive might prove different results. I doubt it; but who knows. I figured my solutions might be helpful for others that just got this laptop and can build of my progress so far.

Comment: It doesn't sound to me like the problem is the fact that you are installing from USB. They sound like genuine Suse issues.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried, or are aware of NDISwrapper?

Excerpt from OpenSuse wiki:

> Some vendors do not release specifications of the hardware or provide a Linux driver for their wireless network cards. The NDISwrapper project implements Windows kernel API and NDIS (Network Driver Interface Specification) API within the Linux kernel. A Windows driver for wireless network card is then linked to this implementation so that the driver runs natively, as though it is in Windows, without binary emulation.

More on the [OpenSuse](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aNdiswrapper) page.

Comment: Spot on Tim! this something I have never heard of! thanks for reading and helping me out!

Comment: Glad to help! Happy Suse'ing!

Comment: The question came up in the review queue, it appears I edited it to pull the rug out from under your answer. Sorry about that :-( Or maybe not, if doing the updates fixed the other problem. I guess OP is happy.